# Update table record based on similarities found between two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: 
surveys, survey_invites, and old_survey_invites.

I migrated old_survey_invites to survey_invites, but created a column called survey_id in survey_invites that should correlate to ‘surveys.id’.

I currently have an inserted value of 1 for all records in survey_invites.survey_id.

How do I update survey_invites.survey_id so that it gets the proper surveys.id value based on the similarities found between surveys.survey_string_key and old_survey_invites.survey_string_key, and surveys.location_id and old_survey_invites.location_id? I was able to come up with a SELECT statement to demonstrate what I'm looking for to some extent:

```
SELECT surveys.id, surveys.location_id, surveys.survey_string_key
FROM surveys
JOIN old_survey_invites 
     ON surveys.survey_string_key = old_survey_invites.survey_string_key 
     AND surveys.location_id = old_survey_invites.location_id 
ORDER BY old_survey_invites.id
```

In summary, I would like to get the surveys.id to put into survey_invites.survey_id based on surveys.survey_string_key = old_survey_invites.survey_string_key and surveys.location_id = old_survey_invites.location_id.

Edit, to migrate from old_survey_invites to the new survey_invites I do:

```
INSERT INTO survey_invites(user_id, user_invitation_id, survey_id,
invitation_date, last_modified_date, survey_link)
SELECT (user_id, user_invitation_id, 1, invitation_date,    
last_modified_date, survey_link FROM old_survey_invites);
```

I put 1 for survey_id as a placeholder.

Comment: What is the link you're looking for between old_survey_invites and the new survey_invites table?

Comment: I'm not looking for a link between old_survey_invites and new survey_invites table. I've migrated some columns from old_survey_invites to the new survey_invites table. I plan to remove old_survey_invites. That being said, there isn't a foreign key between the two, but I have a column in my new survey_invites called survey_id which should be the foreign key to surveys.id. In order to get the proper survey_invites.survey_id I realized I have to check for surveys.id based on surveys.survey_string_key = old_survey_invites.survey_string_key and surveys.location_id = old_survey_invites.location_id.

Comment: Gary wasn't asking about foreign key but about link. In other words: how can we match records from `old_survey_invites` and `survey_invites`. As you wrote, there is already known way of matching `surveys` and `old_survey_invites` but that's not enough to compose an update query for you.

Comment: Would the insert statement used to migrate to the new invites table suffice? I will update my post with that.